# How to group years by 6 months in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I wanted to group the years in my table by six months, similar to grouping by quarter.

[image]

I wanted to find the following result:

| Month of 1. FirstPurchaseDate |  |
| --- | --- |
| March | 2019 |
| August | 2019 |
| February | 2020 |

Is there a way to do this? I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to divide years into semesters then you can try this

```
IF DATEPART('quarter', [Date]) < 3 THEN 'Semester 1' ELSE 'Semester 2' END
```